# How to combine a different provider with the Chef deploy resource?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, lwrp

I am trying to create a recipe to deploy an application.

I would like to combine [the Chef deploy resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html) with the [Chef Mercurial provider](https://github.com/priestjim/chef-mercurial). The readme of this provider suggest that it is easy to use with deploy resource. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

The mercurial resource is working as expected:

```
  mercurial deploy[:deploy_to] do
    repository deploy[:scm][:repository]
    ssh_key "/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    ssh_ignore true
    branch true
    revision deploy[:scm][:revision]
    user deploy[:user]
    group deploy[:group]
    action :sync
  end
```

However I'm having trouble with the provider

```
  deploy deploy[:deploy_to] do
    repository deploy[:scm][:repository]
    user deploy[:user]
    group deploy[:group]
    revision deploy[:scm][:revision]
    environment deploy[:environment].to_hash
    scm_provider Chef::Provider::Mercurial
    action :deploy
  end
```

The error I'm getting is `NoMethodError: undefined method 'ssh_key' for Chef::Resource::Deploy`. This is probably due to the fact that the resource requires the ssh_key attribute. I don't know how to pass this attribute through when using the deploy resource.

How can I make this work?
Does anyone have an example of how to use [the Chef deploy resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html) with the [Chef Mercurial provider](https://github.com/priestjim/chef-mercurial)?

Comment: can you paste in the full error output?

Comment: Yes, here you go http://pastebin.com/QUXVHETB (I replaced some of the names with asterisks)

Comment: interesting.  Looks like a ruby scope thing.  It calls `@new_resource.ssh_key`, but `@new_resource` seems to point to the deploy resource rather than the mercurial or scm one.

Comment: Is this something I'm doing wrong or might this be a bug?

Comment: Looks like the deploy-resource support does not work (anymore). The cookbook was once created and maintained by Opscode/Chef, however the claimed support for the deploy-resource was done by the repo owner. Basically I see two options here a) fork the cookbook and implement deploy support b) write your own Deploy resource that inherits Chef::Provider::Deploy::Revision and deals with the mercurial LWRP from the cookbook

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got the following feedback from the repo owner: "Apparently, my fork needs more work to expose the provider's internal resources to the deploy resource." He also recommends to create a fork and submit a pull request if the problem is fixed. I will try to do so.